# Pivot Table still refers to previous workbook named range

Tags: excel, vba

This is a scenario I've encountered pretty regularly - and worked around it rather than try to solve it.

I have a control workbook with the following worksheets

[image]

In the workbook is a named range "myData" which is the data in sheet "Data".

The `VBA` gets data and pastes it in "Data" then renames the range then refreshes the pivot table which uses the named range as its source. Then the routine copies the sheets `Array("Pivot", "Data", "notes")` into a fresh workbook which gets saved in a different location as "NewWorkbook.xlsx"

Now if I open the NewWorkbook and look at the data source for the pivot it is referring to the original control workbook.

Is there a simple way of making sure the pivot refers to the data in the new workbook? Should I not use a named range?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @SkipIntro it refreshes the workbook and then copies the array of sheets to a new book - nothing unusual - just wondered if anyone had encountered this situation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the sourcedata of the pivotcache

```
Sheets(Array("Data", "Pivot", "notes")).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables(1)
    .PivotCache.SourceData = "myData"
    .RefreshTable
End With
```

for instance

Answer (score 1):

You can also click on the Pivot table tab and redirect it's source from there using the "change source" button and then refreshing as well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIb7u.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: - this is what the question is all about; have you created a model of my question?

Comment: Hi,

I just saw this & tried it again. I created a model. 

To do so I opened up the two workbooks being used.

Then on the sheet with the PivotTable in question I select the "change source" button under the PivotTable tab.

Afterwards I simply selected the new location for the data to read from on the other workbook. 

Also, make sure that the data tabs in the options button are all checked as well. 

Hope this helps